# ways of deserialize json and get specific data

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have a question about deserializing json data. My json data is like that

```
{
"batchcomplete": "",
"query": {
    "pages": {
        "62413": {
            "pageid": 62413,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "espri"
        }
    }
}
```

}

I want to take page id or just the number. The number "62413" is changing each different request.

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void readString()
    {
        requestHelper _req = null;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://tr.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=espri&format=json").Result;
        //var categories = new object { };

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            //categories = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            //dynamic a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
            //Dictionary<string, object> dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(content);

            var b = JObject.Parse(content).Descendants().ToArray();
            var art = b[9];

            _req = new requestHelper { _result = 1, _message = content };

        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_req));
    }


}
```

My codes are like this and this solves my problem but I dont think that this is the best way to do this. My question is that is there any different ways to get what I want? I tried using dictionary but I couldnt figure it out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Eser is right, make a model. Some thoughts: JsonConvert is a little slow, you might want to consider [newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) Also I am seeing a null reference exception (_req will be null ) when your response is not a success, I recommend putting the  `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_req));` inside the if statement.

Comment: thank you for your comment I was just trying to get data so I will rearrange my code after that but thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this model

```
public class Page
{
    public int pageid { get; set; }
    public int ns { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Query
{
    public Dictionary<string,Page> pages { get; set; }
}


public class WiktionaryResponse
{
    public string batchcomplete { get; set; }
    public Query query { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize as

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WiktionaryResponse>(json);
```

Comment: thank you this worked very well I also created classes like that but they have little difference and mine was returning null. I also wanted to hear if there are any other solutions.